# Why after refresh the data will into the array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

when I was calling component.. in that component i am using useEffect for retriving data but problem is after i called component the data array length is zero but after refresh the array data is filled why what happend

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import { getBooksApi } from '../../Redux/actions/booksActions';
import Loader from '../../Utils/loder'
import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router';

const Books = () => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
     const booksData = useSelector(state => state.bookReducer.books);
     const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [books,setBooks] = useState(booksData.length > 0 ? booksData : [])
    // const [ projectId, setProjectId ] = useState("");
    let match = useRouteMatch();

    let history = useHistory();
const handleBook = (id) => {
    history.push(`${match.url}/${id}`);

}


    useEffect(() => {
        
        
dispatch(getBooksApi())



    },[])

if(booksData.length === 0) {
    return <Loader/>
}
else {

    return (
        <div>       
        
         <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-wrap">

        {books.map((book) => {
            return (
    <div className="card col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m-5 rounded book-card" style={{width:400, height:600}}>
  <img src={book.bookImg} className="card-img-top h-50" alt={book.pages}/>
  <div className="card-body ">
    <h5 className="card-title">{book.bookName}</h5>
    <p className="card-text">{book.description}</p>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => handleBook(book._id)}>Click More</button>
  </div>
</div>
            
            )   

        })}

        </div>

        </div>
    )
}



}

export default Books
```

This is my code how to solve this can u help me Thanks in advance

Comment: `books` vs `booksData`? What's the difference? What's in `bookReducer`?

Comment: from bookReducer the data will come, and i will store in one varible and that variable is using in useState... is it ok for that

Comment: Seems like you are duplicating state from redux in the component's local state which is not a great idea.

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/duplication-in-state-management-a-story-of-a-bug-18c0d8206b59

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
useEffect(() => {   
dispatch(getBooksApi())
    },[books]);
```